# Debugging Python and C++ exposed by boost together

Tags: python, c++, debugging, boost, ddd-debugger

I can debug Python code using `ddd -pydb prog.py`. All the python command line arguments can be passed too after `prog.py`. In my case, many classes have been implemented in C++ that are exposed to python using `boost-python`. I wish I could debug python code and C++ together. For example I want to set break points like this :

```
break my_python.py:123
break my_cpp.cpp:456
cont
```

Of course I am trying it after compiling c++ codes with debug option but the debugger does not cross boost boundary. Is there any way?

**EDIT**: 
I saw http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/faq/how_do_i_debug_my_python_extensi.html. 
I followed it and I can do debugging both for python and C++. But I preferably want to do visual debugging with `DDD` but I don't know how to give 'target exec python' command inside `DDD`. If not (just using `gdb` as in the link) I should be able to debug for a Python script not interactively giving python commands as in the link.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but may give you some ideas: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2016-08-09/gdb-example-ncurses.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out how to debug the C++ part while running python. (realized it while reading about process ID detection in Python book..).
First you run the python program which includes C++ programs. At the start of the python program, use raw_input() to make the program wait for you input. But just before that do `print os.getpid()` (of course you should have imported os package). When you run the python program, it will have printed the pid of the python program you are running and will be waiting for your keyboard input.

python stop code  :

```
import os

def w1(str):
    print (str)
    wait = raw_input()
    return

print os.getpid()
w1('starting main..press a key')
```

result  :

```
27352
starting main..press a key
```

Or, you can use import pdb, pdb.set_trace() as comment below.(thanks @AndyG)  and see EDIT* to get pid using `ps -aux`.

Now, suppose the C++ shared library is _caffe.so (which is my case. This _caffe.so library has all the C++ codes and boost python wrapper functions). 27352 is the pid. Then in another shell start gdb like

```
gdb caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/_caffe.so 27352
```

or if you want to use graphical debugging using like DDD, do

```
ddd caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/_caffe.so 27352
```

Then you'll see gdb starts and wait with prompt. The python program is interrupted by gdb and waits in stopped mode (it was waiting for your key input but now it's really in stopeed mode, and it needs gdb continue command from the second debugger to proceed with the key waiting).
Now you can give break point command in gdb like

```
br solver.cpp:225
```

and you can see message like

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7f2cccf70397: file src/caffe/solver.cpp, line 226. (2 locations)
```

When you give `continue` command in the second gdb window(that was holding the program), the python code runs again. Of course you should give a key input in the first gdb window to make it proceed.
Now at least you can debug the C++ code while running python program(that's what I wanted to do)!

I later checked if I can do python and C++ debugging at the same time and it works. You start the debugger(DDD) like `ddd -pydb prog1.py options..` and attach another DDD using method explained above. Now you can set breakpoints for python and C++ and using other debug functions in each window(I wish I had known this a couple of months earlier.. It should have helped tons.).

[image]

EDIT : to get the pid, you can do `ps -aux | grep python` instead. This pid is the next of ddd's pid.

Comment: pdb.set_trace() is probably a better way to get Python to pause, but ultimately they have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but failed to get the solutions in [Chan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39012185/1023390) to work (on MAC OS X 10.12.4). Instead the following worked for me.

1. Write a python script `test.py` that imports and uses the boost.Python module.
2. start python in the debugger

   ```
   lldb python3 test.py
   ```

   giving

   ```
   > lldb python3 test.py
   (lldb) target create "python3"
   Current executable set to 'python3' (x86_64).
   (lldb) settings set -- target.run-args  "test.py"
   (lldb) run
   Process 46189 launched: '/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python3' (x86_64)
   test.cpython-36m-darwin.so was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
   Process 46189 stopped
   * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10d4b3000)
   frame #0: 0x00000001019f49c2 test.cpython-36m-darwin.so`std::__1::enable_if<true, void>::type (anonymous namespace)::Render2D<double>::add_particle<true, 5ul>(float*, float, float, float, float) const [inlined] mylib::SSE::packed<8ul, float>::loadu(
      944        { return {_mm256_load_ps(p)}; }
      945        /// load from unaligned memory location
      946        static __always__inline packed loadu(const element_type*p) noexcept
   -> 947        { return {_mm256_loadu_ps(p)}; }
      948        /// load from aligned memory location, using template arg for alignment
      949        template<bool aligned>

      950        static __always_inline enable_if_t< aligned, packed>
   ```

No need to obtain the pid and start the debugger from a separate window or set any breakpoints.