# how can I debug python and c++ together

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb, pdb

I want to debug python and c++ together. I know gdb can debug c++ code and pdb can debug python code. But how can I debug them together?

For example, I have a python script which calls c++ code. And I want to see the local variables of python script and c++. Is it any way to do that?

Besides, I know how to use gdb to run python to debug c++ code. Don't tell me how to do this... I want to debug them together.

Comment: Realize that what you want and what's possible might be two different things. It's generally better to debug, test, and shore up your C++ code before jamming it in Python for this very reason.

Comment: @tadman I want to read the codes from others...

Comment: If you can get `gdb` to understand Python, which might work, maybe this is possible.

Comment: A bit of a long shot, but If the code is cross-platform and you are willing to switch toolsets for debugging and you have access to a Windows machine you could install Visual Studio 2015 + https://microsoft.github.io/PTVS/ which should do exactly what you ask for.

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb and https://docs.python.org/devguide/gdb.html

Comment: It's not that good. Maybe I wrong, but I still can't use 'print' command to print some variables.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412708/debugging-stepping-through-python-script-using-gdb).

Comment: I think you are debugging python code with C++ exposed to python as python library. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898459/debugging-python-and-c-exposed-by-boost-together.